# How to put a Json object inside other Json object?

Tags: json

I have the following function that gets a course and all the subjects that belong to it.

```
public function getSubjectsPeriodsJson(int $id){
        $student = Student::find($id);
        $course=$student->courses()->latest()->first();
        $subjects = $course->subjects()->get();
        $data = [
            'course' => $course,
            'subjects' => $subjects       
        ];
        return response()->json($data, 200);

    }
```

The way it is right now returns a json response like the following:

```
{
"course": {
"id": 25,
"name": "1A",
"academic_course_id": 18,
"user_id": 2,
"created_at": "2023-02-01T12:51:32.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2023-02-01T12:51:32.000000Z",
"pivot": {
"student_id": 35,
"course_id": 25
}
},
"subjects": [
{
"id": 11,
"name": "matematicas",
"course_id": 25,
"created_at": "2023-02-01T13:00:47.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2023-02-01T13:00:47.000000Z"
}
]
}
```

But I´d like it to be shown as a course with an array of subjects inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should try the way where u create a responseDto of Course i.e., CourseDto
Now CourseDto will have all attributes(fields) which are present in Course .

CourseDto will also contain one more field which is list of subjects .

Now map the output of responses from subject and course to CourseDto.

and then return json response of CourseDto

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).